# Good Java MVC security framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Can anyone recommend me a good authentication security framework that allows the user to be authenticated by an email address as the user name, and allows the user to have a separate screen name?

Comment: MVC design pattern is completely unrelated to application security.

Answer (score 3):

Spring security. It has good features and would work for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out Spring Security:  http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: I did think about that but I can't see a way for authentication to be done using an email and allowing for a screen name.